# How to restart or resume activity

Tags: java, android

i want to restart an activity when i make changes to wifi settings menu if connection is disabled.
this is my code (onCreate method):

```
        boolean status = ConnectionManager.getConnectivityStatusString(this);

    if(status){
        networkStatus.setText("SEI CONNESSO AD INTERNET !");
    }else{
        networkStatus.setText("connection not present");
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MsgAlertConnection newAlertConnection = new MsgAlertConnection();
        newAlertConnection.show(fragmentManager, "Fragment");
    }
```

and this is the code that show a dialog :

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    builder.setTitle("Connection Error !")
           .setMessage("Please check your Internet Connection for start the application.")
           .setPositiveButton("Back to Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   Intent intent=new Intent();
                   intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.WirelessSettings"));
                   startActivity(intent);
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

when a user change the wifi network on "ON", how i restart or resume the application for check network connection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you need to restart the activity - then something is wrong with your design - anyway

```
startActivity(getIntent());
finish();
```

this will do the trick

Comment: onCreateDialog method is in another class that i call in onCreate method..
if connection is disabled, the dialog send the user to wifi settings and turn ON the wifi connection. How i re-check the connection when user return to application ?

Comment: You can raise a flag when sending the user to the network settings, and check the connection in your OnResume() whenever that flag is on

Comment: thanks i'm resolving it by use a boolean. TRUE if the user go to settings page, FALSE if push on Cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

With onRestart method

```
protected void onRestart() {

    super.onRestart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call recreate() from the activity

```
 public void recreate ()
```

Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the first block of code in onResume() method.

When back from WirelessSettings to the activity, the onResume method was called and assign a new value to status var.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this one.

 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    notify("onResume");
  }

or

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // The activity is either being restarted or started for the first time
    // so this is where we should make sure that GPS is enabled
    LocationManager locationManager = 
            (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!gpsEnabled) {
        // Create a dialog here that requests the user to enable GPS, and use an intent
        // with the android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS action
        // to take the user to the Settings screen to enable GPS when they click "OK"
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Activity being restarted from stopped state    
}
```

Please Visit this link.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html